# WCF Post Request content type text/xml

Tags: c#, wcf, post, content-type

i have a problem with a post method..

Here is my interface

```
    public interface Iinterface
    {
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "inventory?")]
    System.IO.Stream  inventory(Stream data);
    }
```

And the function..

```
    public System.IO.Stream inventory(System.IO.Stream data)
    {
    //Do something
    }
```

Well, if from the client sends with content-type text/plain or application/octet-stream works perfect, but the client cant change the content type, and his is text/xml, and i obtain an error..

```
The exception message is 'Incoming message for operation 'inventory' (contract    
'Iinterface' with namespace 'http://xxxx.com/provider/2012/10') contains an
unrecognized http body format value 'Xml'. The expected body format value is 'Raw'. 
This can be because a WebContentTypeMapper has not been configured on the binding.
```

Someone can help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Why can the client not change it's content type? It's just an HTTP request header.

Comment: I ask myself the same question, but he says me that cant do it by any reason..

Comment: You can't expect to send and receive a raw data stream with content type `text/xml`. I believe in this case you will have to write another method on your service to accept xml and then convert to a stream.

Comment: @EkoostikMartin, you **can** send `text/xml` (and `application/json` as well) to an operation receiving a raw data stream. You just need to set the appropriate content-type mapper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error said - you need a `WebContentTypeMapper` to "tell" WCF to read the incoming XML messages as raw messages. You'd set the mapper in your binding. For example, the code below shows how you could define such a binding.

```
public class MyMapper : WebContentTypeMapper
{
    public override WebContentFormat GetMessageFormatForContentType(string contentType)
    {
        return WebContentFormat.Raw; // always
    }
}
static Binding GetBinding()
{
    CustomBinding result = new CustomBinding(new WebHttpBinding());
    WebMessageEncodingBindingElement webMEBE = result.Elements.Find<WebMessageEncodingBindingElement>();
    webMEBE.ContentTypeMapper = new MyMapper();
    return result;
}
```

The post at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2008/04/17/wcf-raw-programming-model-receiving-arbitrary-data.aspx has more information about using content type mappers.